# How do I restart the gRPC server after invoking ShutdownAsync(); under C#?

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm following a tutorial where a gRPC server is declared as:

```
Server server = new Server
{
    Services = { RouteGuide.BindService(new RouteGuideImpl(features)) },
    Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
};
```

Then

```
server.Start();
```

is called, some stuff gets done and finally

```
server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
```

gets called, but when I try

```
server.Start();
```

again, I get the following error:

```
Exception encountered: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at Grpc.Core.Utils.GrpcPreconditions.CheckState(Boolean condition) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core.Api\Utils\GrpcPreconditions.cs:line 88
   at Grpc.Core.Server.Start() in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Server.cs:line 151
```

Should I create a new instance of the server object every time I want to restart it? the Server object does not have Dispose method implemented and I'm worried about memory leaks.

Comment: I think it's better to create a new server object.

Comment: The server object is not reusable and that's working as intended. Once you shut it down (ShutdownAsync() or KillAsync()), the resources will be cleaned up. To create a new server, just create a `new Server()`. It can have the same parameters and listen on the same port as the original server (assuming the old one has already been shutdown successfully).  Btw, shutting down and re-creating a server is a bit unusual use case - normally you'd start a server keep it alive for as long as possible.

Comment: Thanks @JanTattermusch, this was done for a test app where I needed to be able to arbitrarily change the server's port at any time